# linker error from boost/serialization/vector #include

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, linker-errors

I need to use Boost to serialize an std::vector, but when I add the line

```
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
```

to my project, I get an LNK1104 error: cannot open file 'libboost_serialization-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66.lib'. I had, however, already added

```
#include <boost/serialization/array.hpp>
```

without any errors cropping up. Since those two files are in the same folder, I wouldn't think the problem could be that I've overlooked a place where I need to tell Visual Studio where to look for the file. I've tried restarting my computer and closing all code windows in Visual Studio before compiling, so I'm pretty sure it can't be that I have the file open somewhere without realizing it either. What else could it be?

Comment: Boost serialization is not a header only library.  You need to build Boost and link with the relevant library, see: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries

Comment: Linker errors are not caused by missing headers. The error message is pretty clear you need the missing library file, which you need to build following the instructions on the boost site.

Comment: @RichardCritten That was it. This is my first time using an external library, and the fact that I didn't get errors immediately must have been a fluke.

Answer (score 0):

Missing headers is not the problem. You would have a **Cannot include boost/serialization/vector.hpp**

You need to add the directory containing **libboost_serialization-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66.lib** into the **Library Directories** of your project.